# Installing OpenCV on Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: opencv, ubuntu, ubuntu-12.04

I am trying to install OpenCV 2.4.2 on Ubuntu and am running into errors as below:

```
[ 11%] Building CXX object modules/highgui/CMakeFiles/opencv_highgui.dir/src/window_gtk.cpp.o
In file included from /usr/local/include/glib-2.0/glib/gasyncqueue.h:30:0,
             from /usr/local/include/glib-2.0/glib.h:32,
             from /usr/local/include/gtk-2.0/gdk/gdktypes.h:32,
             from /usr/local/include/gtk-2.0/gdk/gdkcolor.h:4,
             from /usr/local/include/gtk-2.0/gdk/gdk.h:30,
             from /usr/local/include/gtk-2.0/gtk/gtk.h:31,
             from /opt/opencv/OpenCV-2.4.2/modules/highgui/src/window_gtk.cpp:48:
/usr/local/include/glib-2.0/glib/gthread.h:233:27: error: variable or field 'g_static_mutex_init' declared void
/usr/local/include/glib-2.0/glib/gthread.h:233:27: error: 'GStaticMutex' was not declared in this scope
/usr/local/include/glib-2.0/glib/gthread.h:233:41: error: 'mutex' was not declared in this scope
/usr/local/include/glib-2.0/glib/gthread.h:233:41: note: suggested alternative:
/usr/include/tbb/mutex.h:48:7: note:   'tbb::mutex'
```

I checked all dependencies and installed them as below:

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential libgtk2.0-dev libjpeg-dev libtiff4-dev libjasper-dev libopenexr-dev cmake python-dev python-numpy python-tk libtbb-dev libeigen2-dev yasm libfaac-dev libopencore-amrnb-dev libopencore-amrwb-dev libtheora-dev libvorbis-dev libxvidcore-dev libx264-dev libqt4-dev libqt4-opengl-dev sphinx-common texlive-latex-extra libv4l-dev libdc1394-22-dev libavcodec-dev libavformat-dev libswscale-dev
```

I also added the following paths to CMakeCache.txt

```
CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE:STRING=-O3 -DNDEBUG -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/glib-2.0/include/ -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gtk-2.0/include/
```

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks,

Sid

Edit : I switched to QT as per comment and that allowed me to get rid of the gtk include that I had to manually insert into CMakeCache.txt. But I was still getting an installation error (maybe due to the glib include) so I turned GSTREAMER off in CMAKE and now I am able to install opencv. Is this work around feasible?

Comment: why are you trying with outdated 2.4.2 ? current opencv stable is 2.4.9, you probably should use that instead

Comment: @berak - I tried with 2.4.9 too and have the same problem

Comment: Why don't you use WITH_QT option, the new Qt based highgui code provides much better functionality than old highgui code that uses GTK. And it doesn't use GTK.

Comment: ah, ok. sorry to hear that ;(

Comment: @ypnos - thanks for the suggestion. however i still get an error   [12%] Building CXX object modules/highgui/CMakeFiles/opencv_highgui.dir/src/cap_gstreamer.cpp.o
In file included from /usr/local/include/glib-2.0/glib/gasyncqueue.h:30:0,
                 from /usr/local/include/glib-2.0/glib.h:32,
                 from /usr/include/gstreamer-0.10/gst/gst.h:27,
                 from /opt/OpenCV-2.4.2/modules/highgui/src/cap_gstreamer.cpp:56:
/usr/local/include/glib-2.0/glib/gthread.h:233:27: error: variable or field 'g_static_mutex_init' declared void

Comment: Can you upload the output of `cmake` function some where (may pastebin.com) and give the link here?

Comment: @AbidRahmanK - Here is the command %cmake -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RELEASE -D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/src -D BUILD_EXAMPLES=ON -D WITH_QT=ON -D WITH_GSTREAMER=ON .. and here is the cmake output http://pastebin.com/NkurvLAe

Comment: Have you tried [this](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/introduction/linux_install/linux_install.html)? But after `git clone` just pick a tag (like 2.4.8, not  2.4.8.2 or .1) [see this for more details of tag] (http://git-scm.com/docs/git-tag)

Answer (score 1):

Curious that you need v2.4.2 when v2.4.9 is the latest release. In any case when following the [build steps](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/introduction/linux_install/linux_install.html#linux-installation) a configuration report is output before the make step that looks like:

```
--
-- General configuration for OpenCV 2.4.2 =====================================
--
--   Platform:
--     Host:                        Linux 3.8.0-29-generic x86_64
--     CMake:                       2.8.7
--     CMake generator:             Unix Makefiles
--     CMake build tool:            /usr/bin/make
--     Configuration:               RELEASE
--
--   C/C++:
--     Built as dynamic libs?:      YES
--     C++ Compiler:                /usr/bin/c++ (ver 4.6.3)
--     C++ flags (Release):         -W -Wall -Werror=return-type -Werror=address -Werror=sequence-point -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wmissing-declarations -Wundef -Winit-self -Wpointer-arith -Wshadow -Wsign-promo -fdiagnostics-show-option -Wno-long-long -pthread -fomit-frame-pointer -msse -msse2 -ffunction-sections -O3 -DNDEBUG  -DNDEBUG
--     C++ flags (Debug):           -W -Wall -Werror=return-type -Werror=address -Werror=sequence-point -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wmissing-declarations -Wundef -Winit-self -Wpointer-arith -Wshadow -Wsign-promo -fdiagnostics-show-option -Wno-long-long -pthread -fomit-frame-pointer -msse -msse2 -ffunction-sections -g  -O0 -DDEBUG -D_DEBUG -ggdb3
--     C Compiler:                  /usr/bin/gcc
--     C flags (Release):           -W -Wall -Werror=return-type -Werror=address -Werror=sequence-point -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wmissing-declarations -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes -Wundef -Winit-self -Wpointer-arith -Wshadow -fdiagnostics-show-option -Wno-long-long -pthread -fomit-frame-pointer -msse -msse2 -ffunction-sections -O3 -DNDEBUG  -DNDEBUG
--     C flags (Debug):             -W -Wall -Werror=return-type -Werror=address -Werror=sequence-point -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wmissing-declarations -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes -Wundef -Winit-self -Wpointer-arith -Wshadow -fdiagnostics-show-option -Wno-long-long -pthread -fomit-frame-pointer -msse -msse2 -ffunction-sections -g  -O0 -DDEBUG -D_DEBUG -ggdb3
--     Linker flags (Release):
--     Linker flags (Debug):
--     Precompiled headers:         NO
--
--   OpenCV modules:
--     To be built:                 core imgproc flann highgui features2d calib3d ml video objdetect contrib nonfree gpu legacy photo python stitching ts videostab
--     Disabled:                    -
--     Disabled by dependency:      -
--     Unavailable:                 androidcamera java world
--
--   GUI:
--     QT 4.x:                      NO
--     GTK+ 2.x:                    YES (ver 2.24.10)
--     GThread :                    YES (ver 2.32.4)
--     GtkGlExt:                    NO
--     OpenGL support:              NO
--
--   Media I/O:
--     ZLib:                        /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so (ver 1.2.3.4)
--     JPEG:                        /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libjpeg.so (ver )
--     PNG:                         /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpng.so (ver 1.2.46)
--     TIFF:                        /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtiff.so (ver 42 - 3.9.5)
--     JPEG 2000:                   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libjasper.so (ver 1.900.1)
--     OpenEXR:                     /usr/lib/libImath.so /usr/lib/libIlmImf.so /usr/lib/libIex.so /usr/lib/libHalf.so /usr/lib/libIlmThread.so (ver 1.6.1)
--
--   Video I/O:
--     DC1394 1.x:                  NO
--     DC1394 2.x:                  YES (ver 2.2.0)
--     FFMPEG:                      YES
--       codec:                     YES (ver 53.35.0)
--       format:                    YES (ver 53.21.1)
--       util:                      YES (ver 51.22.2)
--       swscale:                   YES (ver 2.1.0)
--       gentoo-style:              YES
--     GStreamer:                   NO
--     OpenNI:                      NO
--     OpenNI PrimeSensor Modules:  NO
--     PvAPI:                       NO
--     UniCap:                      NO
--     UniCap ucil:                 NO
--     V4L/V4L2:                    Using libv4l (ver 0.8.6)
--     XIMEA:                       NO
--     Xine:                        NO
--
--   Other third-party libraries:
--     Use IPP:                     NO
--     Use TBB:                     NO
--     Use Cuda:                    NO
--     Use Eigen:                   YES (ver 2.0.17)
--
--   Python:
--     Interpreter:                 /usr/bin/python (ver 2.7.3)
--     Libraries:                   /usr/lib/libpython2.7.so
--     numpy:                       /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/core/include (ver 1.6.1)
--     packages path:               lib/python2.7/dist-packages
--
--   Documentation:
--     Build Documentation:         YES
--     Sphinx:                      /usr/bin/sphinx-build (ver 1.1.3)
--     PdfLaTeX compiler:           /usr/bin/pdflatex
--
--   Tests and samples:
--     Tests:                       YES
--     Performance tests:           YES
--     Examples:                    NO
--
--   Install path:                  /usr/local
--
--   cvconfig.h is in:              /home/vagrant/OpenCV-2.4.2/release
-- -----------------------------------------------------------------
--
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /home/vagrant/OpenCV-2.4.2/release
```

Check this report for any missing libraries and install those dependencies.

I was able to build from source and get past your error on ubuntu 12.04 installing the dependencies you listed:

```
... 
[ 13%] Building CXX object modules/highgui/CMakeFiles/opencv_highgui.dir/src/window.cpp.o
[ 13%] Building CXX object modules/highgui/CMakeFiles/opencv_highgui.dir/src/window_gtk.cpp.o
[ 13%] Building CXX object modules/highgui/CMakeFiles/opencv_highgui.dir/src/cap_dc1394_v2.cpp.o
[ 13%] Building CXX object modules/highgui/CMakeFiles/opencv_highgui.dir/src/cap_libv4l.cpp.o
[ 14%] Building CXX object modules/highgui/CMakeFiles/opencv_highgui.dir/src/grfmt_sunras.cpp.o
[ 14%] Building CXX object modules/highgui/CMakeFiles/opencv_highgui.dir/src/grfmt_pxm.cpp.o
[ 14%] Building CXX object modules/highgui/CMakeFiles/opencv_highgui.dir/src/grfmt_jpeg2000.cpp.o
[ 14%] Building CXX object modules/highgui/CMakeFiles/opencv_highgui.dir/src/grfmt_exr.cpp.o
[ 14%] Building CXX object modules/highgui/CMakeFiles/opencv_highgui.dir/src/grfmt_imageio.cpp.o
[ 15%] Building CXX object modules/highgui/CMakeFiles/opencv_highgui.dir/src/grfmt_jpeg.cpp.o
[ 15%] Building CXX object modules/highgui/CMakeFiles/opencv_highgui.dir/src/grfmt_base.cpp.o
[ 15%] Building CXX object modules/highgui/CMakeFiles/opencv_highgui.dir/src/grfmt_png.cpp.o
[ 15%] Building CXX object modules/highgui/CMakeFiles/opencv_highgui.dir/src/grfmt_bmp.cpp.o
[ 15%] Building CXX object modules/highgui/CMakeFiles/opencv_highgui.dir/src/grfmt_tiff.cpp.o
[ 15%] Building CXX object modules/highgui/CMakeFiles/opencv_highgui.dir/src/bitstrm.cpp.o
Linking CXX shared library ../../lib/libopencv_highgui.so
...
```

Comment: thanks for your response. I notice in your config report, you have Gstreamer set to OFF. Even I was able to build successfully with Gstreamer OFF as mentioned in my Edit. Just wondering if this is a valid work around?

Comment: @sid Those were the default compilation options in my case following the instructions on the opencv site. I would assume their recommendations will work in most cases, unless you know your specific needs are different

Answer (score 1):

Unless you need some specific compilation options, you should be able to install OpenCV right from Synaptic (version 2.3.1); the libraries are already in the default repository.

If you need a newer version, you should also be able to find some PPAs with OpenCV precompiled, such as https://launchpad.net/~yjwong/+archive/opencv2 or https://launchpad.net/~limparissoft/+archive/opencv-ppa

You can find more PPAs in https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+ppas?name_filter=opencv