# failure in compiling opencv with cap_gstreamer error

Tags: c++, opencv, gstreamer

I am trying to compile opencv on Slackware 4.1. However I encountered the following error each time.

```
In file included from /usr/include/gstreamer-0.10/gst/pbutils/encoding-profile.h:29:0,
             from /tmp/SBo/opencv-2.4.11/modules/highgui/src/cap_gstreamer.cpp:65:
/usr/include/gstreamer-0.10/gst/pbutils/gstdiscoverer.h:35:9: error: 'GstMiniObjectClass' does not name a type
typedef GstMiniObjectClass GstDiscovererStreamInfoClass;

/usr/include/gstreamer-0.10/gst/pbutils/gstdiscoverer.h:83:9: error: 'GstMiniObjectClass' does not name a type
typedef GstMiniObjectClass GstDiscovererContainerInfoClass;

/usr/include/gstreamer-0.10/gst/pbutils/gstdiscoverer.h:104:9: error: 'GstMiniObjectClass' does not name a type
typedef GstMiniObjectClass GstDiscovererAudioInfoClass;
     ^
/usr/include/gstreamer-0.10/gst/pbutils/gstdiscoverer.h:129:9: error: 'GstMiniObjectClass' does not name a type
typedef GstMiniObjectClass GstDiscovererVideoInfoClass;
     ^
/usr/include/gstreamer-0.10/gst/pbutils/gstdiscoverer.h:159:9: error: 'GstMiniObjectClass' does not name a type
typedef GstMiniObjectClass GstDiscovererSubtitleInfoClass;
     ^
/usr/include/gstreamer-0.10/gst/pbutils/gstdiscoverer.h:202:9: error: 'GstMiniObjectClass' does not name a type
typedef GstMiniObjectClass GstDiscovererInfoClass;
     ^
In file included from /tmp/SBo/opencv-2.4.11/modules/highgui/src/cap_gstreamer.cpp:65:0:
/usr/include/gstreamer-0.10/gst/pbutils/encoding-profile.h:47:9: error: 'GstMiniObjectClass' does not name a type
typedef GstMiniObjectClass GstEncodingProfileClass;
     ^
/usr/include/gstreamer-0.10/gst/pbutils/encoding-profile.h:66:9: error: 'GstEncodingProfileClass' does not name a type
typedef GstEncodingProfileClass GstEncodingContainerProfileClass;
     ^
/usr/include/gstreamer-0.10/gst/pbutils/encoding-profile.h:85:9: error: 'GstEncodingProfileClass' does not name a type
typedef GstEncodingProfileClass GstEncodingVideoProfileClass;
     ^
/usr/include/gstreamer-0.10/gst/pbutils/encoding-profile.h:104:9: error: 'GstEncodingProfileClass' does not name a type
typedef GstEncodingProfileClass GstEncodingAudioProfileClass;
     ^
/tmp/SBo/opencv-2.4.11/modules/highgui/src/cap_gstreamer.cpp: In member function 'virtual bool CvCapture_GStreamer::grabFrame()':
/tmp/SBo/opencv-2.4.11/modules/highgui/src/cap_gstreamer.cpp:232:57: error: 'gst_app_sink_pull_sample' was not declared in this scope
 sample = gst_app_sink_pull_sample(GST_APP_SINK(sink));
                                                     ^
make[2]: *** [modules/highgui/CMakeFiles/opencv_highgui.dir/src/cap_gstreamer.cpp.o] Error 1
```

The configuration report for the compilation is as follows:

```
-- General configuration for OpenCV 2.4.11 =====================================
--   Version control:               unknown
-- 
--   Platform:
--     Host:                        Linux 3.10.17 i686
--     CMake:                       2.8.12
--     CMake generator:             Unix Makefiles
--     CMake build tool:            /usr/bin/gmake
--     Configuration:               Release
-- 
--   C/C++:
--     Built as dynamic libs?:      YES
--     C++ Compiler:                /usr/bin/c++  (ver 4.8.2)
--     C++ flags (Release):         -O2 -march=i486 -mtune=i686   -fsigned-char -W -Wall -Werror=return-type -Werror=address -Werror=sequence-point -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wmissing-declarations -Wundef -Winit-self -Wpointer-arith -Wshadow -Wsign-promo -Wno-narrowing -Wno-delete-non-virtual-dtor -fdiagnostics-show-option -pthread -march=i686 -fomit-frame-pointer -msse -msse2 -msse3 -mfpmath=sse -ffunction-sections -O2 -DNDEBUG  -DNDEBUG
--     C++ flags (Debug):           -O2 -march=i486 -mtune=i686   -fsigned-char -W -Wall -Werror=return-type -Werror=address -Werror=sequence-point -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wmissing-declarations -Wundef -Winit-self -Wpointer-arith -Wshadow -Wsign-promo -Wno-narrowing -Wno-delete-non-virtual-dtor -fdiagnostics-show-option -pthread -march=i686 -fomit-frame-pointer -msse -msse2 -msse3 -mfpmath=sse -ffunction-sections -g  -O0 -DDEBUG -D_DEBUG
--     C Compiler:                  /usr/bin/cc
--     C flags (Release):           -O2 -march=i486 -mtune=i686   -fsigned-char -W -Wall -Werror=return-type -Werror=address -Werror=sequence-point -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wmissing-declarations -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes -Wundef -Winit-self -Wpointer-arith -Wshadow -Wno-narrowing -fdiagnostics-show-option -pthread -march=i686 -fomit-frame-pointer -msse -msse2 -msse3 -mfpmath=sse -ffunction-sections -O2 -DNDEBUG  -DNDEBUG
--     C flags (Debug):             -O2 -march=i486 -mtune=i686   -fsigned-char -W -Wall -Werror=return-type -Werror=address -Werror=sequence-point -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wmissing-declarations -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes -Wundef -Winit-self -Wpointer-arith -Wshadow -Wno-narrowing -fdiagnostics-show-option -pthread -march=i686 -fomit-frame-pointer -msse -msse2 -msse3 -mfpmath=sse -ffunction-sections -g  -O0 -DDEBUG -D_DEBUG
--     Linker flags (Release):      
--     Linker flags (Debug):        
--     Precompiled headers:         NO
-- 
--   OpenCV modules:
--     To be built:                 core flann imgproc highgui features2d calib3d ml video legacy objdetect photo gpu ocl nonfree contrib stitching superres ts videostab
--     Disabled:                    world
--     Disabled by dependency:      -
--     Unavailable:                 androidcamera dynamicuda java python viz
-- 
--   GUI: 
--     QT 4.x:                      YES (ver 4.8.5 EDITION = OpenSource)
--     QT OpenGL support:           NO
--     OpenGL support:              NO
--     VTK support:                 NO
-- 
--   Media I/O: 
--     ZLib:                        /usr/lib/libz.so (ver 1.2.8)
--     JPEG:                        /usr/lib/libjpeg.so (ver 80)
--     PNG:                         /usr/lib/libpng.so (ver 1.4.12)
--     TIFF:                        /usr/lib/libtiff.so (ver 42 - 3.9.7)
--     JPEG 2000:                   build (ver 1.900.1)
--     OpenEXR:                     build (ver 1.7.1)
-- 
--   Video I/O:
--     DC1394 1.x:                  NO
--     DC1394 2.x:                  YES (ver 2.2.2)
--     FFMPEG:                      NO
--       codec:                     NO
--       format:                    NO
--       util:                      NO
--       swscale:                   NO
--       gentoo-style:              NO
--     GStreamer:                   
--       base:                      YES (ver 0.10.36)
--       video:                     YES (ver 0.10.36)
--       app:                       YES (ver 0.10.36)
--       riff:                      YES (ver 0.10.36)
--       pbutils:                   YES (ver 0.10.36)
--     OpenNI:                      NO
--     OpenNI PrimeSensor Modules:  NO
--     PvAPI:                       NO
--     GigEVisionSDK:               NO
--     UniCap:                      NO
--     UniCap ucil:                 NO
--     V4L/V4L2:                    Using libv4l1 (ver 0.9.5) / libv4l2 (ver 0.9.5)
--     XIMEA:                       NO
--     Xine:                        NO
-- 
--   Other third-party libraries:
--     Use IPP:                     NO
--     Use Eigen:                   NO
--     Use TBB:                     NO
--     Use OpenMP:                  NO
--     Use GCD                      NO
--     Use Concurrency              NO
--     Use C=:                      NO
--     Use Cuda:                    NO
--     Use OpenCL:                  YES
-- 
--   OpenCL:
--     Version:                     dynamic
--     Include path:                /tmp/SBo/opencv-2.4.11/3rdparty/include/opencl/1.2
--     Use AMD FFT:                 NO
--     Use AMD BLAS:                NO
-- 
--   Python:
--     Interpreter:                 /usr/bin/python2 (ver 2.7.5)
-- 
--   Java:
--     ant:                         NO
--     JNI:                         /usr/lib/java/include /usr/lib/java/include/linux /usr/lib/java/include
--     Java tests:                  NO
-- 
--   Documentation:
--     Build Documentation:         NO
--     Sphinx:                      NO
--     PdfLaTeX compiler:           /usr/share/texmf/bin/pdflatex
--     Doxygen:                     YES (/usr/bin/doxygen)
-- 
--   Tests and samples:
--     Tests:                       YES
--     Performance tests:           YES
--     C/C++ Examples:              NO
-- 
--   Install path:                  /usr
-- 
--   cvconfig.h is in:              /tmp/SBo/opencv-2.4.11/build
```

I looked through the opencv requirement from below link

http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/introduction/linux_install/linux_install.html#linux-installation

That I need ffmpeg or libav packages, which I cannot find under standard slackware 14.1 packages.  But I installed gstreamer completely instead (gstreamer, gst-pluigns-base, and good) and the error I encountered above definitely has something to do with gstreamer.

Answer (score 10):

I got this fixed by installing `libgstreamer-plugins-base1.0-dev`. Before that CMake detected GStreamer version 0.10.36, after that - 1.4.5.

Answer (score 3):

It worked for me after I set WITH_GSTREAMER_0_10 to ON

Comment: This works perfectly and does not disable gstreamer, as other answers suggest to do...not sure why it was downvoted, either.

Comment: I also was able to install opencv with this option. Very good answer

Answer (score 1):

I am using Ubuntu 12.04 but got the same error.
This can be avoided by using the **-D WITH_GSTREAMER=OFF** parameter.
As advised [here](http://code.opencv.org/issues/3953) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23669638/installing-opencv-on-ubuntu-12-04).

Then [here](https://gist.github.com/melvincabatuan/c8a95cf4beef39614ce0) they advise to update gstreamer, but this didn't fix it for me.
I still want to verify this with a fresh installation.

Comment: Seems like OP wanted gstreamer...why recommend disabling it?

Answer (score 0):

If anybody still have problem with that, 
try to install gstreamer1.0 properly with all that packages

Example for Fedora OS:

```
dnf install gstreamer1-devel gstreamer1-plugins-base-tools 
gstreamer1-devel-docs gstreamer1-plugins-base-devel 
gstreamer1-plugins-base-devel-docs 
gstreamer1-plugins-good gstreamer1-plugins-good-extras 
gstreamer1-plugins-ugly gstreamer1-plugins-ugly-devel-docs  
gstreamer1-plugins-bad-free gstreamer1-plugins-bad-free-devel
gstreamer1-plugins-bad-free-extras
```

Here is comprehensive installation guide for your system: [official link.](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/installing/on-linux.html)